# how bad is it to have multiple active intervals functions in a react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, setinterval, intervals

I have a schedule application with a changing number of "rows" objects in a schedule array that represents appointments (each day can have diffrent number of appointments).

I want to add to the schedule a red time mark that represents the current time in relationship to the ongoing appointemnt and updates every minute. The problem is that I need to put an intervel function in each row commponent (in order for the time mark to be fully reactive during the day, also each appointment can have diffrent duartion), which means that up to 50 intervals can be active at the same time..
how bad is it to have multiple active intervals?
thanks!

Comment: _"I need to put an intervel function in each row commponent"_ I'd bet this is not true. You probably should have one interval at the top level that updates state in some way, and then all the row components would simply re-render with that new state. But without any code I can't tell you how that would work. Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question so we have something to work with.

Comment: you are correct , and i can have one higher level interval, which is obviously better. the downside is that logic of the time mark is pretty far up in the component tree. anyways the question still  intersts me, how bad is it to have multiple intervals active?

Comment: You could have thousands of you wanted. There’s no real limit so long as your CPU can resolve the callbacks fast enough. But that just seems like a bad approach for what you describe.

Comment: yeah you are correct, now its much better with one interval, i wonder if i should also add logic to stop the interval after the last appointment and also to start the interval when the first appointment starts or just let the interval run all day.., if its only one interval every 60 seconds with pretty easy calculation it doesnt seem so bad comapring to the effort of writing the logic, maybe for future refactoring. any thoughts?